# Function update contact is not defined, although it is defined

Tags: javascript, angular

I have here angular code :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail-view',
  templateUrl: './detail-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail-view.component.css']
})
export class DetailViewComponent implements OnInit {

    detailLable:string; 
    contactId: number;
    contact:Contact = null; 

    constructor(
    private contactService: ContactService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.contactId = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if(this.contactId == 0){
        this.contact =  {id : null, firstName : null, surname : null, email: null, phone: null};
        this.detailLable = 'New contact'
    } else {
        this.contactService.getContact(this.contactId).subscribe(contact => this.contact = contact);
        this.detailLable = 'Edit contact with id :' + this.contactId; 
    }
  }

  updateContact( contact: Contact): void{
    this.contact = contact;
    this.detailLable = "Edit contact with id " +contact.id
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }

  save():void {
    // this.contact = this.contactService.saveContact(this.contact).subscribe(contact => this.contact = contact,   complete: () => console.log(this.detailLable = this.contact.id));
     this.contactService.saveContact(this.contact).subscribe(contact => updateContact(contact));
  }

  new() : void {
      this.contact =  {id : null, firstName : null, surname : null, email: null, phone: null};
  }
}
```

when I call save, It return me that updateContact method is not defined. Can someone give me a point, how to solve this issue? It seems, that is something wrong with method declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updateContact` is defined on the class, so `this.updateContact` should work.

Comment: Thank you, thats it.